# Не совсем понимаю как работает генератор yield в python

Tags: python, генераторы, yield

В целом этот вопрос скорее про генератор yield (я не совсем понимаю как он работает), а не про работу с байтами пикселей.

Есть код:

```
def get_pixel(path):
    img = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    pix = img.load() #список всех пикселей изображения. При обращении по координатам возвращает значение трех байтов
                     # указанного пикселя(RGB компоненты)

    width = img.size[0]
    height = img.size[1]

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            print(f'from loop: {pix[x,y]}')
            yield pix[x,y] #возвращает кортеж с 3 числами, значения байт RGB
            print('after yield')


for x in range(10):
    r, g, b = get_pixel('pics/cat.png')
    print(r, g, b, "из внешнего цикла")
```

Мне нужно:
Чтобы при каждом обращении к функции get_pixel() она отдавала мне следующий пиксель согласно внутреннему циклу.
Например, я обратился к функции первый раз и она вернула мне пиксель с координатами [0,0].
Я обратился к ней второй раз и она отдала мне пиксель с координатами [0,1]. Третий - [0,2]. Пятьсот двенадцатый - пиксель с координатами [1,0] (ширина изображения 512 пикселей).
Пятьсот четырнадцатый - [1, 2].

Соответственно когда я вызываю эту функцию get_pixel() в цикле 10 раз, и присваиваю на каждой итерации переменным r, g, b значения из кортежа из 3 чисел, который возвращает yield, и я ожидаю увидеть 10 выводов функции print(r, g, b, "из внешнего цикла"), но на деле получаю в консоли вот что:

```
from loop: (107, 107, 108)
after yield
from loop: (118, 119, 122)
after yield
from loop: (118, 120, 119)
after yield
from loop: (118, 118, 118)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python projects\SpyCats\test2.py", line 19, in <module>
    r, g, b = get_pixel('pics/cat.png')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Хотя по моей логике мы во внешнем цикле вызываем функцию get_pixel, внутри этой функции находятся 2 цикла, и когда мы натыкаемся на оператор yield, то он как и оператор return возвращает значение-кортеж pix[x, y], этот кортеж мы присваиваем переменным r,g,b во **внешнем** цикле и выводим их на экран через print(). После этого происходит следующая итерация внешнего цикла и мы начинаем с того же самого места в функции get_pixel(), в котором закончили - т.е. с оператора yield. Происходит следующая итерация внутри функции get_pixel() и yield возвращает уже следующее значение pix[x,y] (с другой координатой x).
Но это так не работает. Вывод в консоль какой-то совсем не понятный. Почему так?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить значения из генератора, по нему нужно **итерироваться**. Например, вот так можно получить какое-то количество значений по одному:

```
pixels = get_pixel('pics/cat.png') # получили собственно генератор
for x in range(10):
    r, g, b = next(pixels) # берём следующее значение (кортеж) из генератора
    print(r, g, b, "из внешнего цикла")
```

Хотя обычно просто перебирают все значения генератора, итерируясь по нему сразу от начала и до конца:

```
for r, g, b in get_pixel('pics/cat.png'):
    print(r, g, b, "из внешнего цикла")
```

Осталось только объяснить вот это:

> Вывод в консоль какой-то совсем не понятный.

```
r, g, b = get_pixel('pics/cat.png')
```

Здесь происходит **распаковка**, то есть опять же итерирование правой части равенства в попытке "добыть" из неё нужное количество значений. Три раза итерация прокатывает - интерпретатор получает три **кортежа** значений, которые он помещает соответственно в переменные `r, g, b` (да, в каждой из этих переменных теперь целый кортеж, а не одно значение, как вы задумывали), но по правилам тут итерирование не заканчивается, правая часть равенства должна быть проитерирована целиком (хотя см. дальше), всё что там есть должно быть распаковано. Но это делается экономно (как обычно для генераторов, чем они и хороши) - после четвёртой итерации выясняется, что очередное полученное значение некуда присваивать в левой части равенства, тут выходит ошибка и всё прекращается.